# Number of Comparisons in Bubble Sort

Tags: java, comparison, counter, bubble-sort

I am trying to make a method for comparisons in my bubble sort class. However, I keep getting the same value. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks.

```
public void comparisons(int[] array)
{
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
{
 for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++)
 {
   count++;
   if ((array[i] > array[i + 1])) //Swaps the elements
   {
     int temp = array[i]; 
     array[i] = array[i + 1];
     array[i + 1] = temp;
   }
 } 
}
System.out.print("\n\nComparisons:" + count);
}
```

Comment: The number of comparisons, according to your code, is always `n*(n+1)/2` where `n = array.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop index *i* is the same value for all the values of *j* in the inner loop.  Looks like the compare logic should be using the inner loop index *j*.

If count is supposed to record the number of swaps done during the sort, perhaps it needs to be in the block of code performing the swap.  At the moment, count++ will always execute the same number of times.

Comment: I made the change but it still prints the same value

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop index `j` is not used, and it has incorrect bounds.

```
public void comparisons(int[] array)
{
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
{
 for (int j = i; j < array.length - 1; j++)
 {
   count++;
   if ((array[j] > array[j + 1])) //Swaps the elements
   {
     int temp = array[j]; 
     array[j] = array[j + 1];
     array[j + 1] = temp;
   }
 } 
}
System.out.print("\n\nComparisons:" + count);
}
```

Comment: It still prints the same number everytime

Comment: Are you always sorting arrays of the same size?  The number of _comparisons_ is **exactly determined** by `array.length`,  and **by `array.length` alone**.  Perhaps you want to count the number of **swaps** instead?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
public void comparisons(int[] array)
{
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
{
 for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++)
 {
   if ((array[i] > array[i + 1])) //Swaps the elements
   {
     int temp = array[i]; 
     array[i] = array[i + 1];
     array[i + 1] = temp;
     count++;
   }
 } 
}
System.out.print("\n\nComparisons:" + count);
}
```

You better try to increment value of **count** inside the if-condition. You can place `count++` anywhere inside if-condition, based upon requirements.